# Tell if a specific entry in column B exists for an ID in column A

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I tell which values in Column A do not have a value of '320' in column B.

```
SELECT A.FORM_ID, B.FIELD_ID 
FROM TABLE_A 
INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.FORM_ID = TABLE_B.FORM_ID
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT distinct A.FORM_ID 
FROM TABLE A 
where not exists (select 1 from TABLE B where A.FORM_ID = B.FORM_ID and B.Field_Id = 320)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `A.FORM_ID` and set a condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT A.FORM_ID
FROM TABLE_A A INNER JOIN TABLE_B B 
ON A.FORM_ID = B.FORM_ID
GROUP BY A.FORM_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN B.FIELD_ID = '320' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

The condition can also be written with COUNT():

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN B.FIELD_ID = '320' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT A.FORM_ID
  FROM      TABLE_A     A
 INNER JOIN TABLE_B     B
        ON A.FORM_ID = B.FORM_ID

EXCEPT

SELECT A.FORM_ID
  FROM TABLE_A      A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B  B
        ON A.FORM_ID = B.FORM_ID
WHERE B.FIELD_ID = 320
```

It's like doing a substraction.